# Mocked object returns null

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

JUnit test class :

```
public class TestingClass {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    private HttpEntity entity;

    @Mock
    private ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        MockitoHelper.initMocks(this);

    }

    @Test
    public void getDataTest() {

        ClassToTest c = new ClassToTest(restTemplate);

        when(restTemplate.exchange("http://testing", HttpMethod.GET, entity, Resource.class)).thenReturn(responseEntity);
        c.getData("http://testing");

    }

}
```

Class being tested :

```
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Optional;

public class ClassToTest {

    private HttpHeaders headers;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ClassToTest(RestTemplate restTemplate){
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    public Optional<InputStream> getData(final String mediaUrl) {

        Validate.notEmpty(mediaUrl);

        final String requestJson = "{}";
        final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestJson, headers);
        Optional inputStreamOptional = Optional.empty();

        try {
            final ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(mediaUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Resource.class);
            System.out.println(responseEntity);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        return inputStreamOptional;
    }
}
```

The result of `System.out.println(responseEntity);` is `null` .

Should `responseEntity` be set to it's mocked value and returned (instead of current behavior where null is returned) as is configured in : `when(restTemplate.exchange("http://testing", HttpMethod.GET, entity, Resource.class)).thenReturn(responseEntity);`

So when `c.getData("http://testing");`is invoked the mocked `responseEntity` is returned ?

Update use instead :

```
when(restTemplate.exchange(Matchers.eq("http://testing"), Matchers.eq(HttpMethod.GET), Matchers.isA(HttpEntity.class), Matchers.eq(Resource.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely returning null because your parameter definition in `when` and the actual parametes differ. In your case it's very likely that your mocked `entity` and the `HttpEntity` you're creating in your code under test are neither the same nor equal. So you need to widen your expectations in the `when`-definition. You should use Matchers in your definition and the could use `isA(HttpEntity.class)` for your entity.

Comment: thank you, this did the trick : when(restTemplate.exchange(Matchers.eq("http://testing"), Matchers.eq(HttpMethod.GET), Matchers.isA(HttpEntity.class), Matchers.eq(Resource.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);

Answer (score 1):

I think that you don't need to mock `ResponseEntity`, since ResponseEntity is not the one being injected. You mocked `ResponseEntity` and then never mocked any of its methods , that's why its `null`.

You need to mock `RestTemplate` and then mock its:

```
when(restTemplate.exchange("http://testing", HttpMethod.GET, entity, Resource.class)).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is centered around this line in your test:

```
when(restTemplate.exchange("http://testing", HttpMethod.GET, entity, Resource.class)).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

What this says is to return your mock responseEntity when you call restTemplate.exchange with these *specific* arguments.  Notice that one of those arguments is your mock entity.  However, in your ClassToTest, that mock entity is not what's passed into restTemplate.exchange.  So when you run your test, you never hit the exact method signature expected by your stub.

Try this, instead:

```
when(restTemplate.exchange(eq("http://testing"), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(Resource.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

This replaces the specific parameters with matchers, and will cause your stubbed method to trigger on *any* HttpEntity rather than the specific mock one.

Note that if you use any matchers at all, you have to use matchers for *all* the parameters, which is what the `eq()` method is for.